# Inner glow with gradient illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I want to create following text effect glow in illustrator, not sure from where I get.

[image]

Comment: The intensity and distance of the glow look arbitrary. So I suspect it was brushed (using same gradient  as the circle fill)

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. This probably wasn't created in Illustrator, but it could be done using gradient mesh or by applying blurs to shapes. You're likely to get a better answer if you say what you have tried so far or show your current progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't an Inside Glow effect. For sure it was hand painted, probably in a pixel based painting app.

You can do it easy BTW with blurred shapes.
If you want it to looks like hand made then you have to draw the outline then blur it. Then mask it with the text as clipping mask.
If instead you want a photoshop like basic inner glow, then simply duplicate text add some stroke, blur it, then mask it.

Made a few frame illustration. I hope it helps.
[image: Made a few frame illustration. I hope it helps.]